# locate some files and append the content in python

Tags: python, file, text, append, locate

I am trying to find all the files with name ACC.txt in a given folder and its subfolder and then append them to create a new file i.e. output_file.txt. All the files are not in the working directory.

I have written the following code, but it is throwing a empty file.Please correct the code

```
import os
import shutil
BASE_DIRECTORY = r'E:\equity research\test_data'
with open('output_file.txt','wb') as wfd:
  for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(BASE_DIRECTORY):
       for filename in filenames:
             if filename == "ACC.txt":
                 fullPath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                 with open(fullPath,'rb') as fd:
                     shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd)
```

Comment: Could not reproduce, did you check that you enter the copyfileobj function? Add a trace (e.g print) to check that your script accesses the ACC.txt files

Comment: Apologies Nico238, I am new to python and not clear on what exactly you meant be " enter the copyfileobj function". I did gave print command for variable "fullpath". It did printed out correct fullpath along with the file name. I hope you meant the same.

Comment: no problem it is what I meant. Print the fllpath, sourround the shutil.copfileobj with a ```try:\n print('copy %s in output.txt'%fullpath)\n shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd)\n except (IOError, os.error) as why:\n print('error in copy : ' +str(why))``` and wait unitl your script finished to open the result file somtetimes python may decide to flush the opened file at the end of process.